# Prevent user from accessing some routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

Working on a Laravel application and I have some routes, the routes are of a multi step form. I need to prevent the user from accessing the last route (which directs to last page of the form) before accessing or filling in the previous routes.

**Routes**

```
Route::get( '/first', 'TrController@payQuote')->name('b2c.payquote');
Route::get( '/second', 'TrController@emailQuote')->name('b2c.sendquote');
Route::get( '/receipt', 'TrController@getReceipt')->name('b2c.receipt');
Route::get( '/success', 'TrController@getSuccess')->name('b2c.success');
```

Comment: Broadly speaking you can have middleware that checks whether the previous route has been completed by the user. What that middleware will contain though greatly depends on how you've implemented everything. I'll assume that the first second and receipt part results are stored in the session or a database so you can retrieve them in the middleware

Answer (score 4):

You could create a middleware class and then use the middleware directly in your `routes` file.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckPermission
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // TODO: Add your logic here.

        if ($request->age <= 200) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in your routes file:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware(CheckPermission::class);
```

Comment: beaten by 55 secs, BTW, here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. One way could be that you can check http-referrer on the last page and if it is the route previous to the last one then you allow it otherwise redirect it to the previous page. This can be implemented for every page.

Other way could be database driven. For every page visit you can have an entry in the database and check on the next page if there is an entry otherwise redirect him to wherever you want.

Comment: ,, Thanks, on your suggesstion how can I use http-referrer to prevent user from accessing last page before filling any of the previous pages..

Comment: In your controller check for url()->previous() or URL::previous() or you can have a middleware to check the same.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-url

Comment: Or if you can apply a middleware to the last route to check this instead of it going in to the controller. Also - Not an answer but instead of using multiple pages, you could look at something more single page. Take a look at Chaining modals (queue) example on this link: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples