# Laravel - How to prevent access to a page until user completes a certain task

Tags: php, laravel-8

The idea is : a user, after login, has to complete a survey to be able to access other routes. I want to block those routes until the survey is submited, I'm still learning Laravel so I dont know if this could be done with a middleware or sessions or javascript code or .. ?

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for SO as answers will be opinion-based. SO is for specific problems about programming, usually with some code involved. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guides for more info. Try some tutorials, have a go at implementing your solution, if you get stuck post the details here, showing what you tried, and describe what happened, why it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could have a field in your database to track whether or not a user has done the survey.  Maybe you want the survey for every login, so maybe it could be a flag in the session.

Comment: I want an example code of how to get a variable, that is not an in input or in databse, from elsewhere and test it in middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old, but as explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125332/1766113, you can use a middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckPermission
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // TODO: Add your logic here.

        if ($request->survey_submitted == true) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in your routes file:

```
Route::get('survey/survey-2', function () {
   //
})->middleware(CheckPermission::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in laravel with a middleware

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you please clarify with a code example ?

Answer (score 0):

check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware it's a very comprehensive documentation with a clear example on how to implement it

Comment: Yes indeed, but I have no idea how to pass variable from form to middleware, I know the logic is to set a variable to true if the form is complete and to test it in the middleware.. In documentation variable is an input from user but here it is not

Comment: You can ask me whatever you want, I am here to help! I suggest you to watch tutorial videos about registering middleware and creating the logic. @1K412